# SQL Optimization in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

We are using Oracle 11 and I recently acquired a Dell SQL Optimizer (included with the Xpert Toad package). We had a statement this morning that was taking longer than normal to run, and after we eventually got it running (missing some conditions from when it was created) I was curious, having never used any SQL optimizer before, what it would change it to. It came back with over 150 variations of the same statement, but the one with the lowest cost simply added to the following line.

```
AND o.curdate > 0 + UID * 0
```

We already had o.curdate > 0, and the "+ UID * 0" was added. This decreased the runtime from over a minute to 3 seconds. I assume it has something to do with how Oracle translates and processes the conditions, but I was curious if any of the Oracle gurus would be able to provide some insight as to how this addition to the greater than zero check decreased the runtime by 15 times. Thanks!

Comment: Check the execution plans for both statements.

Comment: Without the full query, it is very hard to say anything other than you need to check the execution plans.  My best guess is that this prevents using an index on `curdate`, which might have been suboptimal.  Updating statistics could have had the same effect.

Comment: I did that as suggested, but the statement with the change isn't showing a plan through Toad. I did notice in the SQL Optimizer software that it is doing a full table scan on four tables (one being ORDERS which is aliased as 'o'), and with the change there are no full table scans.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The UID * 0 is used to hide the 0 from the optimizer. The optimizer would use its statistic data to find out whether using an index scan on `o.curdate > 0` makes sense. As long as the optimizer knows the value in `o.curdate > value` it will do so. But when the value is unknown (here because the function UID will be called on execution and somehow mathed into the value), the optimizers cannot foresee what percentage of rows may be accessed and thus choses an avarage best access method.

Example: You have a table with IDs 1 to 100. Asking for ID > 0 will result in a full table scan, whereas asking for ID > 99 will likely result in an index range scan. When asking for ID > 0 + UID * 0 suddenly makes the optimizer blind to the value, and it may chose the index plan rather then full table scan.

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes a lot of sense! I need to dig more into how these statements work exactly for future reference, little details like this go a long way in efficiency, I would imagine. As I commented above, the first statement was doing full table scans on four of the tables (one of them being the table containing curdate), and with this addition it is no longer doing any according to the optimizer software...not sure why Toad isn't showing the plan for the second statement. Thanks again!