# Literal Performance in Oracle SQL Where Clause

Tags: oracle, performance

I have a moderately complex query that was taking ages to run in some cases, so I let Dell SQL Optimizer have a crack at optimizing it. It's started doing a lot of modifications like this one:

```
WHERE 5 = table.column_name
-- becomes
WHERE 5 + ORA_INVOKING_USERID * 0 = table.column_name
```

Queries like this seem to perform slightly better in its analysis, but I'm skeptical that'll work out in production.

Is this any faster? If so, why?

Comment: can you add your query explain plan with == >> " EXPLAIN PLAN FOR select....." and  "  select * from table(dmbms.xplan.display)  " and table and index create script.

Comment: This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26587745/409172).  These conditions are probably a way of changing Oracle's cardinality estimates; perhaps this prevents Oracle from using the min/max, or a histogram, or a SQL plan directive, or some other feature.  In my opinion this is a good reason to avoid using that program.  This looks one of those old-school, unscientific Oracle "optimizations" that leads to myths.  At the very least, a program should add a comment to explain what it's doing when it's doing something cryptic.

Comment: The parser/optimiser can perform simple arithmetic with literals, so it will treat `150 - 25 * 2` as `100`, but it can't know `ORA_INVOKING_USERID` at runtime so it will fall back on one of its rules of thumb.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I wonder if the modern optimiser is good enough to eliminate `ORA_INVOKING_USERID * 0` completely. It seems like a trick that could have worked in SOME WEIRD WAY on Oracle 7 though.